# Get second last row of a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

If getting the first/last row is as following:

```
TableRow lastRow = theTable.Elements<TableRow>().Last();

TableRow firstRow = theTable.Elements<TableRow>().First();
```

How to select the second last row?

Comment: What is the second last? Do you mean the row before last?

Comment: @Hamlet Yes, the row before last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
TableRow firstRow = theTable.Elements<TableRow>().Reverse().Skip(1).First();
```

Note, that this expression can throw an exception if no suitable row is available (also `Last` and `First`).

Comment: Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow>' to 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Thank you, mixed your previous answer with dasblinkenlights and got what i wanted, looks exactly like your current version :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the count, you can find `k`-th element from the back by subtraction, like this:

```
var k = 2; // Second element from the back
var total = theTable.Elements<TableRow>().Count();
if (total < k) throw ... // Not enough elements
var kThFromBack = theTable.Elements<TableRow>().Skip(total-k).First();
```

Comment: did you mean `if (total < k) throw ...` ??

Answer (score 0):

Made a little extension method:

```
public static T NthLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    if (count < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("count must be >= 0");

    int i = 0;
    var queue = new Queue<T>(count);

    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            queue.Enqueue(e.Current);

            if (i++ > count)
                queue.Dequeue();
        }

        if (count >= i)
            throw new ArgumentException("count was greater than length");
    }

    return queue.Dequeue();
}
```

To get second last element:

```
var secondLast = theTable.Elements<TableRow>().NthLast(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one

```
TableRow lastButOneRow= theTable.Rows[theTable.Rows.Count-2]
```

Comment: You should add a check to you dont try too lookup index -1

Comment: @Jf Beaulac: Assumed that table has at least two rows.